# Сгруппировать строк таблицы SQL и добавить идентификатор группы

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть множество(>100к) строк, необходимо по значениям их столбцов сгруппировать и записать для строк идентификатор получившейся группы.

Необходимые столбцы содержат текст.
Например: 
Столбец `url` содержащий ссылку на сайт компании. 
Столбец `name` содержащий имя компании, здесь наверное основная проблема, так как требуется сравнивать по значению строки до запятой.

Если обе строки совпадают - присвоить им уникальный идентификатор группы.

Возможно ли выполнить это на чистом `mysql` ?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. вы бы привели пример входных данных и свои попытки реализации.

Comment: версия mysql не помешает

Comment: `select distinct substring_index(name,',',1) as name, url` и потом пронумеровать что ли, или как?

Comment: а, вам проапдейтить таблицу, вписав в каждую строку номер группы по уникальной паре название-урл

Comment: @teran вроде такого, да, теперь нужно номера групп записать в отдельный столбец

Comment: @teran версия 10.0.33-MariaDB-wsrep

Comment: `dense_rank()` вам там номера групп сделает

Comment: а чистый `mysql` то вам зачем, если у вас `mariadb` ?

Answer (score 1):

вдруг кому пригодится, вариант на SQL Server

исходные

```
DECLARE @data table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    group_num int null
);

INSERT INTO @data (id, name, url)
VALUES 
  (1, 'Рога, ООО', 'http://gooogle.com'),
  (2, 'Рога, ООО1', 'http://gooogle.com'),
  (3, 'Рога, ООО2', 'http://yandex.ru'),
  (4, 'Рога, ООО3', 'http://mail.ru'),
  (5, 'Копыта, ООО1', 'http://gooogle.com'),
  (6, 'Копыта, ООО2', 'http://yandex.ru'),
  (7, 'Копыта, ООО3', 'http://yandex.ru'),
  (8, 'Копыта, ООО4', 'http://bing.com'),
  (9, 'Копыта, ООО5', 'http://bing.com?search=google');
```

апдейт

```
UPDATE x
    SET group_num = g
FROM (
    SELECT id
          ,name
          ,url
          ,group_num
          ,dense_rank() over (order by substring(name, 0, charindex(',', name)) ,url) as g        
    FROM @data
) AS x;

select * from @data;
```

в MariaDB тоже есть `dense_rank()`, а вместо `substring` и `charindex` можно использовать `substring_index(name, ',', 1)`

фиддл без табличных переменных http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc247/2

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно создать записи в другую таблицу с данными уникальными значениями?
Что-то вроде такого получается:

1. Создаём базу данных:

   > CREATE TABLE table_name (
   >   ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   >   CompanyName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   >   URL varchar(255),
   >   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
   >   );
2. Заполним её новыми данными:

   > INSERT INTO table_name (CompanyName, URL)
   >   VALUES n.CompanyName, n.url From
   >   (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',' ,1) as CompanyName, url from YourTable) n

Comment: где вы взяли про новую  таблицу? в комментах же обсудили, что надо сделать апдейт